# Last-child of a certain class isn't working

Tags: html, css

Can any body tell me how I use `last-child` selector to style my last `div` of `subs`?

This is my HTML -

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="subs"></div>
  <div class="subs"></div>
  <div class="subs"></div>
  <div class="subs"></div>
  <div class="paginate"></div>
</div>
```

I tried it something like this in my CSS -

```
div.main div.subs:last-child {
   border: none;
}
```

But its not working. If I remove `paginate` div, then it is working. So can I know how can I style last `subs` div without any extra id or class declaration.

Thank you.

Comment: TRY TO USE   div.paginate { border: none !important; }

Comment: What browser are you using (hint: `last-child` is not supported in IE8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is only ever 1 element succeeding your `.subs` (`.paginate`), you can use this:

```
div.main div:nth-last-child(2) {
   border:none;
}
```

See this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLBnk/)

This can be seen as a little hacky, and if your paginate element is ever absent, then the wrong sub element will be targeted. Your only other option is to give the `.subs` their own container and *then* use `:last-child`:

Another [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLBnk/1)

---

**P.S:** To understand why `:last-child` isn't working the way you want it to, I really recommend also reading [Spudley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17967694/1612146).

Comment: Yes this is working for me. I tried with `nth-last-child` selector before ask this question. But I couldn't figure it out. Can you explain how this works. Thank you.

Comment: @TNK `nth-last-child(n)` targets the element relative to the last element in the scope, using the parameter. (1) being the last element, (2) being second from last, etc..

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is because of `:last-child` doesn't work the way you think it does.

The `:last-child` selector will select an element *only if it is the last child of its parent*.

In the case of your `.main` element, the last child inside it is the `.pagination` div. This means that `.main>*:last-child` can *only* select the pagination div. It doesn't matter if you filter it down by specifying `.subs`; you can't select anything else using `:last-child` because none of the other elements are the last child of `.main`. If the actual last child element isn't in the filtered selection, it will select nothing rather than selecting something that isn't the last child.

The best way to work around this is to wrap your `subs` elements inside an additional layer of markup, so that the last one then does become the last child of that container element. Either that, or move the pagination element outside of the `main` element; whatever works best for your layout.

The other selector you might have tried, `:last-of-type` works in a similar way. For the time being, there isn't a CSS selector you can use instead to pick the last `.subs` element, using your current markup. (unless you're happy to go with `:nth-last-child(2)` which will pick the second-last child, on the assumption that the pagination div will always be present).

In the new selectors being designed for CSS4, there is a set of 'match' selectors that would do exactly what you want to do. You would use `:nth-last-match(1)` to get the last matching element. This is the selector you need. Unfortunately, it isn't available in current browsers, and there's no real hint yet as to when (or even whether) it will be available in the future. For the time being, [you can read about it here](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/), but not use it. You might be able to use it or something similar via a JS library like jQuery.

Hope that helps explain things to you.

Comment: Additional; official documentation: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#selected-child-index

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you add an extra class name to the last element. http://jsfiddle.net/5FQck/

```css
div.main div {
    border: #000 thin solid;
}

div.main div.subs.last {
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="subs">subs</div>
  <div class="subs">subs</div>
  <div class="subs">subs</div>
  <div class="subs last">subs</div>
  <div class="paginate">pagination</div>
</div>
```

[None of the following selectors work in IE 8 and below](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions), primarily because they are all CSS3 selectors.

- `:nth-child(N)`
- `:nth-last-child(N)`
- `:nth-of-type(N)`
- `:nth-last-of-type(N)`

---

You could also add that new class to the last element using JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/5FQck/1/

```js
$('div.main div.subs:last').addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I would do it like this.

```
.main .subs:nth-child(4)
{
     border:none;
}
```

Comment: What happen If I have more div with a class of 'subs' than 4?

Comment: The i would use :last-of-type instead.. :)